# How to reproduce the same cell pattern around different indexes?

Tags: rust, geospatial, h3

I am using [H3](https://h3geo.org/) spatial index implementaion [h3o](https://docs.rs/h3o/latest/h3o/). I want to encode a local cell pattern to draw it around a given index.

The first problem is that I am inevitably going to fight pentagons, but I don't care about warping the pattern around them. So handling of pentagons is reduced to preventing panics.

The second problem is that as I understand it is impossible to fix the order in which cells are walked during calls of [`grid_disk_distances_safe`](https://docs.rs/h3o/latest/h3o/struct.CellIndex.html#method.grid_disk_distances_safe). Thus I can't encode the pattern by enumerating neighboring cells.

I think that there is no information in the index that can help me either. [Index encodes](https://h3geo.org/docs/core-library/h3Indexing/) the path from the base cell to desired one through layers and does not contain spatial information about neighbors' order.

### The question

How to encode the pattern of cells to reproduce it around a given index?

Answer (score 0):

The solution and related discussion is [here](https://github.com/HydroniumLabs/h3o/issues/15). The code for transition function is as follows.

```rust
fn transpose_pattern(src: CellIndex,
                     dst: CellIndex, 
                     pattern: &[CellIndex]) -> Vec<CellIndex> 
{
    // Compute translation offset.
    let src_coord = src.to_local_ij(src).expect("src coord");
    let dst_coord = dst.to_local_ij(dst).expect("dst coord");
    let i_offset = dst_coord.i() - src_coord.i();
    let j_offset = dst_coord.j() - src_coord.j();

    // Transpose the pattern from src to dst.
    pattern
        .iter()
        .copied()
        .map(|cell| {
            // Compute the local IJ coordinate wrt original center cell.
            let src_ij = cell.to_local_ij(src).expect("local IJ");
            // Apply translation and re-anchor at destination center cell.
            let dst_ij = LocalIJ::new_unchecked(dst, src_ij.i() + i_offset, src_ij.j() + j_offset);
            // Convert back to cell index.
            CellIndex::try_from(dst_ij).expect("dst cell")
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

All credit for the provided solution goes to [grim7reaper](https://github.com/grim7reaper).